Nvidia driver incompatible error issue with isaac sim 2023.1.1
I'm trying to run Isaac Sim on a VM with NVIDIA driver version 535 and a kernel version of 5.10.28. While launching Isaac Sim in Docker (using Ubuntu 20.04 as the base image), I'm encountering an error: "Driver incompatible. vkCreateInstance failed. Vulkan 1.1 is not supported, or your driver requires an update." I've tried multiple NVIDIA driver versions, but the issue persists.
Does anyone know the exact NVIDIA driver version that supports this configuration, or have any possible solutions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I tried with multiple Nvidia drivers and was expecting any one of them would be compatible, and I would be able to run Isaac sim.


The 5.10 kernel is not a supported kernel of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GA = 5.4, HWE = 5.15) so are you using Ubuntu? or a Ubuntu based system that uses the Debian kernel (5.10) as your provided details do not match a Ubuntu product.

I am using debian kernel with 5.10, but i am building the docker which uses ubuntu 20.04 as base image.
